# OnClick change JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an index.html file with two buttons as:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="pages/page1.html" target="_blank">Load init-a.js file</a>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="pages/page1.html" target="_blank">Load init-b.js file</a>
```

If I click on **button 1**, `page1.html` and `page2.html` files should Load `init-a.js` file until I came back to index.html page and click on other option.

If I click on **button 2**,

```
<script src="../js/init-a.js"></script>
```

The above tag should be changed as below...

```
<script src="../js/init-b.js"></script>
```

in page1.html and page2.html files

**PS**: By default I am loading `init-a.js` file in all the html pages

**[Online Demo](http://www.pixelfoxy.com/hello/index.html)**

> I have many clients such as Lenovo, Philips, Samsung... and I want to maintain only one set of prototype (more than 100 html pages)..
>
> **Eg**, If I want to give a demo for lenovo, By clicking / selecting Lenovo option, I will just load
>   `lenovo.js` file to get the lenovo related data, for philips demo `philips.js` file... 
>   relevant content will be loaded in all html pages which will be easy
>   for maintanance, instead of creating different folders for each client

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/master.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="pages/page1.html" target="_blank">Load init-a.js file</a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="pages/page1.html" target="_blank">Load init-b.js file</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

init-a.js

```
$("h1.init-heading").html("Heading from <span>init-a.js</span> file");
$("p.init-paragraph").html("Paragraph from <span>init-a.js</span> file");
$("ul.init-list").replaceWith("<ul><li>Item 1 from from <span>init-a.js</span> file</li><li>Item 2 from from <span>init-a.js</span> file</li><li>Item 3 from from <span>init-a.js</span> file</li></ul>");
```

init-b.js

```
$("h1.init-heading").html("Heading from <span>init-b.js</span> file");
$("p.init-paragraph").html("Paragraph from <span>init-b.js</span> file");
$("ul.init-list").replaceWith("<ul><li>Item 1 from from <span>init-b.js</span> file</li><li>Item 2 from from <span>init-b.js</span> file</li><li>Item 3 from from <span>init-b.js</span> file</li></ul>");
```

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/master.css">
</head>

<body>

    <a href="page2.html" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">>> Go to Page 2</a>

    <h1 class="init-heading">{Main Heading}</h1>
    <p class="init-paragraph">{Paragraph}</p>
    <ul class="init-list">
        <li>{Dummy item 1}</li>
        <li>{Dummy item 2}</li>
        <li>{Dummy item 3}</li>
    </ul>

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/init-a.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It is always loading the init.a.js file :(... If I click on button 2, page1 and page2 should load init-b.js file, instead of init-a.js file

Comment: Are you trying to create some form of single page app where `page1/2.html` are partials? otherwise your just moving to those pages on button click and can include your scripts on them as normal.

Comment: **@ste2425**.. no, these are simple html pages for prototype purpose to show it to the client

Comment: Should you provide to us the content of page1.html?

Comment: I believe that you should approach your problem differently. Load both files and execute a different behavior based on the button clicked

Comment: @hvnis... added the page1.html to the question... also please find the all files at **http://www.pixelfoxy.com/hello/index.html**

Comment: You only import init-a.js script, it's a cause of this problem. I think, you should use path parameter Ex: page1.html?btn=1. if (btn =1) { import script a} else {import script b}. This is my sugguestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as I am understanding your question, You want to load JavaScript file dynamically. Here are some ways to load js file dynamically. You can use either of them.

```
function loadjscssfile(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
```

You can trigger this function in onclick event of your link.button.

The jQuery library also provides loading functionality in one line:

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){
     alert("Script loaded.");
});
```

Following two links can also help you.

1. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml
2. [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Example:
You have following link in your code. Give some id to this like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="pages/page1.html" id="some_id" target="_blank">Load init-a.js file</a>
```

Now in your main javascript file (Which is you are using in your whole project), add following onclick function

```
$("#some_id").click(function(){
     //call above function like this.
     loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js");
});
```

Comment: should I need to add above script in index.html? or inside html pages? Please suggest me as I am **Innocent at Scripting** :)

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you would want to do that. I have a simpler solution. 
You could just simply include init-b.js in your html 2 since it's separate pages. I find it really weird to use buttons to load javascript files to pages dynamically.

Comment: I have many clients and one generic html set of prototype... for example, If I want to give a demo for lenovo, I will just load lenovo.js file, for philips demo philips.js file... So that all relevant content will be loaded in all html pages which will be easy for maintanance...